# Spark structured streaming join not working

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm fairly new to Spark structured streaming, and I'm trying to join several streams together, coming from Kafka topics (Spark 2.3.2, Kafka 2.0)

Joining works nicely on streams where I can do simple equi-joins on keys. On one particular join from 2 topics I must do some data conversion, because on one topic the join key is encoded in hex, whereas on the other it's in base64.

After a lot of debugging, I came to the following code, which I'm testing in a PySpark Zeppelin notebook. The 2 topic streams are stored in a Python dict

```
debug = (topicStreams['invprop']
   .where("invpropv.PHC_UID_IPID = '183C1BA9B3444919B6C33DAB0B639A87'")
   .writeStream.outputMode("append").format("memory")
   .queryName("debug").start()
)
```

This returns exactly one message from the first topic, as I would expect

```
debug2 = (topicStreams['hca']
   .where("hex(unbase64(hcav.id)) = '183C1BA9B3444919B6C33DAB0B639A87'")
   .writeStream.....
```

This second stream also returns one messages, those are of course the 2 messages I'm trying to join. I think I can assume that the keys indeed match.

```
debug3 = (topicStreams['invprop']
   .join(topicStreams['hca'], 
         expr("invpropv.PHC_UID_IPID = hex(unbase64(hcav.id))"))
   .writeStream...
```

This join never returns anything. What would cause this join to fail? I must be overlooking something basic, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as always, writing a Stackoverflow question always provides an answer. This time in quite an unexpected way...

Typing the question above took me a couple of minutes and then I checked again my Zeppelin notebook. Lo and behold, I now got the single joined record that I was looking for.

The join is just awfully slow, but it works - it took over 5 minutes to produce a result. I never waited long enough before. And no, the topics are not terribly big, the hold a few 10s of thousands of messages only.

Well, now I know that the join is basically working. I have to find out why it is so slow, and how I can speed it up.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Pyspark but I could see that in Python compare operator is `==` instead `=` as in your code.
Please re-check what `=` operator do inside `expr()` function

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That code inside expr() is actually Spark SQL code, so the single = is correct there